# Oozie Spark access to hive with kerberos

Tags: hive, oozie, spark-java, oozie-workflow, mit-kerberos

When I execute a spark process in oozie I have the following error. The database not found.

```
2018-09-26 15:27:23,576 INFO [main] org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client: 
     client token: Token { kind: YARN_CLIENT_TOKEN, service:  }
     diagnostics: User class threw exception: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.NoSuchDatabaseException: Database 'zdm_datos_externos' not found;
     ApplicationMaster host: 10.74.234.6
     ApplicationMaster RPC port: 0
     queue: default
     queue user: administrador
     start time: 1537986410475
     final status: FAILED
     tracking URL: https://BR-PC-CentOS-02:26001/proxy/application_1537467570666_4127/
     user: administrador
```

[image]

[image]

This is my spark config

```
    String warehouseLocation = new File("spark-warehouse").getAbsolutePath();
    SparkSession spark = SparkSession
            .builder()
            .appName("Java Spark Hive Example")
            .master("yarn")
            .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", warehouseLocation)
            .config("spark.driver.maxResultSize", "3g")
            .config("spark.debug.maxToStringFields", "10000")
            .config("spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled", "true")
            .enableHiveSupport()
            .getOrCreate();
    spark.conf().set("spark.driver.maxResultSize", "3g");
```

> metastore, current connections: 1 2018-09-26 17:31:42,598 WARN [main]
>   hive.metastore: set_ugi() not successful, Likely cause: new client
>   talking to old server. Continuing without it.
>   org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException
>            at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.read(TIOStreamTransport.java:132)
>            at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:86)
>            at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readStringBody(TBinaryProtocol.java:380)
>            at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readMessageBegin(TBinaryProtocol.java:230)
>            at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:77)
>            at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$Client.recv_set_ugi(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:3748)
>            at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$Client.set_ugi(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:3734)
>            at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.open(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:557)
>            at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:249)
>            at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.(SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.java:74)
>            at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>            at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>            at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>            at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1533)
>            at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:86)
>            at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:132)
>            at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:104)
>            at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createMetaStoreClient(Hive.java:3157)
>            at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:3176)
>            at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getAllFunctions(Hive.java:3409)
>            at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.reloadFunctions(Hive.java:178)
>            at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.(Hive.java:170)
>            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>            at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.security.HiveCredentialProvider$$anonfun$obtainCredentials$1.apply$mcV$sp(HiveCredentialProvider.scala:91)
>            at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.security.HiveCredentialProvider$$anonfun$obtainCredentials$1.apply(HiveCredentialProvider.scala:90)
>            at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.security.HiveCredentialProvider$$anonfun$obtainCredentials$1.apply(HiveCredentialProvider.scala:90)
>            at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.security.HiveCredentialProvider$$anon$1.run(HiveCredentialProvider.scala:124)
>            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>            at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
>            at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1778)
>            at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.security.HiveCredentialProvider.doAsRealUser(HiveCredentialProvider.scala:123)
>            at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.security.HiveCredentialProvider.obtainCredentials(HiveCredentialProvider.scala:90)
>            at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.security.ConfigurableCredentialManager$$anonfun$obtainCredentials$2.apply(ConfigurableCredentialManager.scala:82)
>            at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.security.ConfigurableCredentialManager$$anonfun$obtainCredentials$2.apply(ConfigurableCredentialManager.scala:80)
>            at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
>            at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
>            at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
>            at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
>            at scala.collection.MapLike$DefaultValuesIterable.foreach(MapLike.scala:206)
>            at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:241)
>            at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.flatMap(Traversable.scala:104)
>            at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.security.ConfigurableCredentialManager.obtainCredentials(ConfigurableCredentialManager.scala:80)
>            at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.prepareLocalResources(Client.scala:430)
>            at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.createContainerLaunchContext(Client.scala:915)
>            at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.submitApplication(Client.scala:195)
>            at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.run(Client.scala:1205)
>            at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$.main(Client.scala:1261)
>            at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.main(Client.scala)
>            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>            at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:761)
>            at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:190)
>            at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:215)
>            at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:129)
>            at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
>            at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SparkMain.runSpark(SparkMain.java:113)
>            at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SparkMain.run(SparkMain.java:104)
>            at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMain.run(LauncherMain.java:47)
>            at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SparkMain.main(SparkMain.java:38)
>            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>            at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMapper.map(LauncherMapper.java:238)
>            at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:54)
>            at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:459)
>            at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
>            at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:187)
>            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>            at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)

Comment: Did you dump `hive-site.xml` to the container's working directory, with a `<file>` instruction?

Comment: When I do that, an error is generated.
Error: Workflow submission failed.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Spark are you using?  Did you enable Hive support on your sparkSession?

```
sparkBuilder.enableHiveSupport().appName(appName).getOrCreate()
```